# WindowLeaked error driving me crazy

Tags: android, android-asynctask, onclicklistener

I have an activity that uses async task to handle Web Services consumption, but im getting an error when i enter the activity or click in one of the buttons, it seems that the ProgressDialog is not closing ok, im missing someting here? any ideas would be helpful!

**Error Log:**

```
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.roneskinder.selfierush.activity.TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{45400170 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-180,180} that was originally added here
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:436)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at com.roneskinder.selfierush.login.util.CustomProgressDialog.show(CustomProgressDialog.java:41)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at com.roneskinder.selfierush.activity.TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity$asyncGetTaskClass.onPreExecute(TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity.java:84)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at com.roneskinder.selfierush.activity.TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity.onCreate(TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity.java:44)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.roneskinder.selfierush.activity.TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{45428730 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-180,180} that was originally added here
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:436)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at com.roneskinder.selfierush.login.util.CustomProgressDialog.show(CustomProgressDialog.java:41)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at com.roneskinder.selfierush.activity.TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity$asyncRateClass.onPreExecute(TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity.java:156)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at com.roneskinder.selfierush.activity.TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity.asyncRateTask(TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity.java:64)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at com.roneskinder.selfierush.activity.TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity$2.onClick(TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity.java:58)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4630)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19339)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-28 08:24:28.589: E/WindowManager(20301):      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Activity:**

```
package com.roneskinder.selfierush.activity;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.roneskinder.selfierush.login.R;
import com.roneskinder.selfierush.login.util.CustomProgressDialog;
import com.roneskinder.selfierush.login.util.UserFunctions;

public class TaskFactoryRateTasksActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG_GETTASK = "getRateTask";
    public static final String TAG_RATETASK = "RateTask";

    protected TextView taskDescription, taskDescriptionExtra, taskScore;
    protected Button btn_like, btn_dislike;

    public String idtask, description, description_extra, score, rate, message, response;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.task_factory_ratetask_layout);

        taskDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taskDescription);
        taskDescriptionExtra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taskDescriptionExtra);
        taskScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taskScore);

        btn_like = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_like);
        btn_dislike = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dislike);

        new asyncGetTaskClass(this).execute();

        // Like 
        btn_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rate = "1";
                asyncRateTask(v);
            }
        });

        // Like 
        btn_dislike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rate = "0";
                asyncRateTask(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void asyncRateTask(View v) {
        new asyncRateClass(this).execute();
    }

    public void setTextViews(){
        taskDescription.setText(description);
        taskDescriptionExtra.setText(description_extra);
        taskScore.setText(score);
    }

    class asyncGetTaskClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public asyncGetTaskClass(Context ctx) {
            progressDialog = CustomProgressDialog.ctor(ctx);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // sleep for 5 seconds
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.getRateTask();


            try {

                // news found
                // Getting Array of News
                JSONArray emailLogin = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GETTASK);
                // Log.d("JSON", "NEWS: " + news);

                if (emailLogin != null) {
                    // looping through All News
                    for (int i = 0; i < emailLogin.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = emailLogin.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        idtask = c.getString("idtask");
                        description = c.getString("description");
                        description_extra = c.getString("description_extra");
                        score = c.getString("score");

                        Log.d("TASK INFO", "Task:" + idtask + "\ndescription:" + description + "\ndescription_extra:" + idtask + "\nscore:" + score);

                    }

                } else {
                    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                    Log.d("Login empty: ", json.toString());
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                if (null != progressDialog && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                }
                setTextViews();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    class asyncRateClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public asyncRateClass(Context ctx) {
            progressDialog = CustomProgressDialog.ctor(ctx);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // sleep for 5 seconds
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.RateTask(rate, idtask);

            try {

                // news found
                // Getting Array of News
                JSONArray emailLogin = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RATETASK);
                // Log.d("JSON", "NEWS: " + news);

                if (emailLogin != null) {
                    // looping through All News
                    for (int i = 0; i < emailLogin.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = emailLogin.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        response = c.getString("response");
                        message = c.getString("message");

                        Log.d("TASK INFO", "response:" + response + "\nmessage:" + message);

                    }

                } else {
                    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                    Log.d("Login empty: ", json.toString());
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                if (null != progressDialog && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                }
                if(response.equals("1")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TaskFactoryMenuActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("response", "2");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TaskFactoryMenuActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("response", "3");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your CustomProgressDialog class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `progressDialog.dismiss()` instead of `progressDialog.hide()`. There is a subtle difference between the two:

`dismiss()`:

> Dismiss this dialog, removing it from the screen.

`hide()`:

> Hide the dialog, but do not dismiss it.

When you no longer need the dialog you don't hide it under the bed, you shoo it away with dismiss. :P

Comment: Damn! so simple, i was blocked need some sleep